# Need help with Salesforce Process Builder

Tags: salesforce-id

I want to add lead in the campaigns automatically based on lead source. For that I am using process builder and object I am choosing is Lead `source = web` and the Immediate action I am choosing is create a Record based on campaign id which I already have in salesforce.

But when I am adding lead and lead `source = web` but it wont letting me save the record and giving me the error

Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID `3011a00000016uz`. Contact your administrator for help.

Please help me where I am wrong

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Xn7AAE) which is 'In Review' as of now. The suggested workaround is to just try it again (I know that sucks!) and it works/ fails intermittently.

Comment: There are number of processes in my org, but in the error there is only version id mentioned. How can I know the process name? Is there a way to find the name of the process from version id?

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you're getting that is you're forgetting a field of some sort of error with adding the Campaign Member... possibly?

Look at this image and make sure you've got it setup correctly:

[image]

If that isnt it... another option would be to simply fire a Flow instead of just using Process Builder.  You could do the Record Create in your Flow and hopefully ignore whatever Process Builder is erroring at... I don't see that error happen 'randomly' with an actual Flow.  Process Builder is always a bit buggy so I usually just use it to trigger a Flow and do all my work in there for that very reason.

Comment: So what was the right answer?  Was it your Process Builder being updated or did you go with a Flow?

Comment: Hi David I have made the process as per your instructions and it worked fine for a day and now if I am changing the lead status its throwing error.  A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 301390000004Mzi

Comment: Vip - the issue would be that you're creating a Campaign Member twice.  I'll update my post to include an image of where you check the box to make someone only once.